# Return checked checkboxes when user retrieves the form (Coldfusion)

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

So, I have a form where user checks a few checkboxes. When user submits, the values of checkboxes are stored in the database. What I am trying to do is, when user logs in again and retrieves the form, the checkboxes should appear to be checked. Is there a way to do this in Coldfusion?

```
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="delegations" id="SPR" value="0" /></t> Student Payment Request 
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="delegations" id="ECR" value="1" /> E-Procurement Check Request</br>
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="delegations" id="ARR" value="2" /></t> Advance Request/Reconciliation
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="delegations" id="PC" value="3" /> Petty Cash
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="delegations" id="CR" class="CR" value="4" /> Chromeriver
```

Comment: Step 1 - See if the user has ever checked anything before.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has shown no effort to solve the problem himself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use cfparam in these case like above.

```
<cfparam name="form.delegations" value="#yourQuery.columnname#" />
```

And in HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="delegations" id="SR1" value="0" <cfif listFind(form.delegations,0)>checked</cfif> />
```

Please note, in your database the value will be a list of values from checkboxes delegations.

Comment: BIG RED FLAG: You should not store the selected values as a list in a single record. You should store the data in a proper many to many relationship where the table looks something like `[parent ID | delegation ID]`. This means that if you select 3 check boxes, you have 3 records. When you query the DB for this data, you can use ColdFusion's `ValueList()` function to convert the contents of the "delegation ID" column into a comma delimited list that can be used with `listFind()`.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use boolean logic for this. If they checked the box, it'll fill out a column in the database upon submission called `isChecked` with the value `1`.

If you query that value, you can program in conditions with the result.

Example:

```
<cfinput type="checkbox" name="delegations" id="SPR" value="0" <cfif queryname.isChecked eq 1> checked </cfif> />
```

This will load the checkbox as filled in if the database says it is.

Comment: If you are using XHTML style, it should also have `checked="checked"`